# Spring Classpath : Not able to read file inside JAR

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss-eap-6, jboss-developer-studio

I am using jboss developer studio. I am having two projects InventoryCommon(JAR)and InventoryWeb(WAR-dynamic web project,Spring MVC+Hibernate).InventoryCommon is having a mappings package inside src.InventoryCommon is present on classpath of InventoryWeb.From inside the aplicationCOntext of InventoryWeb. I am referring to mappings package as classpath:mappings(having hbm files) and I getting filenotfoundexception.I checked the same in deployment location.the mappings folder is present.Even then I am getting filenotfound exception.What might be missing here,Do we have something specific to jboss eap or jboss dev studio. I already have tried classpth*:,But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are occasionally problems with definitions of deployment descriptors, in 'Developer studio'. I struggled with those too. Instead, you need to set up two Maven projects: *InventoryWeb*, with a dependency on the second Maven project *InventoryCommon*. The Jar-project InventoryCommon needs to be compiled first. Afterwards, your War-project InventoryWeb needs to be Maven compiled. This will provide you with a working War-file, to be deployed under for example Tomcat.

Ensure that no Java EE dependencies are included in your Maven projects if you deploy on Tomcat.

JBoss Developer Studio was designed to work with JBoss Application Server, which is now WildFly. All web-programming there is in Java Enterprise (EE), not Spring. Deployment in WildFly needs to be performed either via JBoss Developer studio, or by uploading the War in the administrator console of WildFly.